# Build extension for an external android application

Tags: android

I don't think it is possible but maybe someone could prove me wrong.
I would like to build an android application that will extend\interact with another external application already installed on the system. For example, I would like to create a bar that whenever a user views a chat on whatsapp it will show at the top of the screen and will be able to interact the with the whatsapp application (let's say, when I click a button on the bar it will insert text into the message box).

I found system overlays, which allows me to run a widget on top of all applications but there is no way to interact with the other applications. 
I don't think it is possible because every application has its own activities and views and from another application I can't interact with them unless the allow it in some way.

Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there is no doubt, your in wrong way by very much. In android application runs in sandbox, so they cannot use other application data or contents by data i mean here files that are in data/data directory, database, assets, and application specific contents (like componets, resources - (images from drawables, files contents from raw folder, all ui elements). By all means some data can be compromised with some conditions like database, some data/data files by contents providers if other application wishes it do so then only. Other than launching it you cannot do anything.

Comment: I am not looking to build a real extension to the external app that will use its files, resources and manipulate its data. I want to build another application that will be able to get a reference to, for example, an exterenal app ui element and interact with it. I will have my own data and resources, all I want is to interact with other apps, mainly their ui elements while they are shown on the screen

Comment: For that u  should be owner of the both apps , so u can customise how you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to interact with other applications if they are not designed for that purpose.